# Doctrine convert SQL with subquery to DQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine and DQL function `createQuery()` and I have this query :

```
SELECT id, 1 + (
    SELECT count( * )
    FROM user a
    WHERE a.points > b.points ) AS RNK, points
FROM user b
```

This query return a rank calculated with the field `points`.

How can I convert this query for use in createQuery() ?

For now I have :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
    SELECT id, 1+(
        SELECT count(*) 
        from AppBundle\Entity\User a 
        WHERE a.points > b.points) as RNK, points 
    FROM AppBundle\Entity\User b
");
```

But this return a syntax error : `"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 14: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'"`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
SELECT b.id, 1+(
    SELECT count(a) 
    from AppBundle\Entity\User a 
    WHERE a.points > b.points) as RNK, points 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\User b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to get the number of the same entity (USER), why not simply do :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
    SELECT u.id, 1+count(u.*) as RNK, u.points FROM AppBundle\Entity\User u
");
```

from the doc : [doctrine chap 14.2.4](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) :

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM Entities\User u');
```